# CI4 You must use the "set" method to update an entry. Already use set, still error

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to update a single record with a single column to be updated by the Codeigniter 4 Framework. It's been 3 hours and I still can't get it works, the docs and the error itself is extremely unclear to me:

`You must use the "set" method to update an entry`

So far, I tried this:

```php
public $books;
public $validation;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->books = new Book();
    $this->validation = Services::validation();
    $this->validation->setRules([
        'title' => 'string|max_length[100]',
        'content' => 'string|min_length[20]|max_length[2000]'
    ]);
}

public function borrow($id)
{
    if (!$this->books->find($id)) {
        session()->setFlashData('error', 'No book.');
        return redirect()->to('/books');
    }

    $data['borrower'] = $this->request->getVar('borrower');

    // ERROR: You must use the "set" method to update an entry. 
    $this->books->where('id', $id);
    $this->books->set($data);
    $this->books->update('books');

    // ERROR: You must use the "set" method to update an entry. 
    $this->books->find($id)
        ->update($id, $data);

    // ALSO ERROR: You must use the "set" method to update an entry. 
    $this->books
        ->whereIn('id', [$id])
        ->set($data)
        ->update();

    // AGAIN, ERROR: You must use the "set" method to update an entry. 
    $book = new Book();
    $book->update($id, $data);

    // STILL, ERROR: You must use the "set" method to update an entry. 
    $book->whereIn('id', [$id])
        ->set($data)
        ->update();

    return redirect()->to('/books');
}
```

Any clue?

*EDIT*

I forgot to add the `var_dump` here we go:

```php
var_dump($id);
var_dump($data);
die;

// RESULT: ['id'] => '3'
// RESULT: ['borrower'] => 'Jane doe'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My gosh! Just realized I didn't specify the `borrower` field inside the `protected $allowedFields` entry.

```php
// Book model.
protected $allowedFields = [
  'title',
  'content',
  'borrower' // <-- This thing was the problem, it isn't here before.
];

// Book controller.
// Now it works.
$this->books->update($id, $data);
```

Comment: Since you already answered the question may I give you some more pointers on things you shouldn't be doing. Since your using the codeigniter model functions please consider doing the validation in the model. Also in your controllers consider not using the __construct method but the initController provided by codeigniter, because using the construct can give you problems while accessing your $request